# How to determine whether a SQL server or database exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-connection

My database owner does not have any rights to the master database, and I am looking for a way to find out whether a SQL Server server exists, and whether a database exists on that server.

Comment: It seems a valid question, so upvoted, but would be nice to see what you have tried already.

Comment: after down voting, people should write justification, so that i could find weaknesses too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162151) to manage the SQL server object model.

Answer (score 0):

First let us check if an instance of sqlserver is available on the local machine.

This can be done through SMO ([reference of SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210334.aspx) and [another reference](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=34)) like

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

DataTable dataTable = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);//if true is passed it
//will enumerate local instance only.

foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable)
{
    if ((dataRow["Server"] as string) == "MyServerName")
        Console.WriteLine(dataRow["Instance"] as string);
}
```

Then to check if the required database is available use this :

use the function db_id which returns the Id of the database if it exists, otherwise null. Example T-SQL below:

```
if (db_id('INVENTORY') is null)
begin
    return 0
end
else
begin
    return 1
end
```

hope this helps.

Comment: i already seen this answer in existing threads. this is a slower process, it takes too much time in query server instance. actually, in my desktop application scenario, i want to test if instance is running and database is up every time, when desktop application starts. most of the time(90%) database will be up. using above said method, it will take some extra time in querying server instance, which will make application startup slower.